# How to make make size of image responsive with flex layout Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I would like to make size of image responsive with respect to size of screen but it dies not work. I would like to show whole image in small screen but it is showing only half of the image. If someone know what is the issue then let me know. Thanks

```
<div class="flex-container" 
 fxLayout="row" 
 fxLayout.xs="column">
  <div class="flex-item" fxFlex=50>  
      <img alt="image" src="../assets/image.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item" fxFlex=33>
     <img  alt="image" src="../assets/image.png"/>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it as follow:

```
 <div fxFlexFill class="example-container">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="32px" [style.height]="'100%'">
      <mat-card class="card-margins">
        <mat-card-title></mat-card-title>
          <div
            fxLayout="row"
            fxLayoutGap="32px"
            fxLayout.lt-sm="column"      
            fxLayoutGap.lt-sm="10px">
            <div fxFlex="0 100 100%">
                <img mat-card-image src="../assets/image.png" alt="Free image">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div fxFlex="0 0 calc(50%-36px)">
            <mat-card-content>
              <p>Hi, how are you?</p>
            </mat-card-content>
            </div>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
```